# Jenkins integration with Git repository

Tags: git, jenkins

1. I have installed git 2.7 on my centos server. and created repository at /srv/repo.git. i am able to clone this using the command `ssh://user@serverIP:/srv/repo.git`.
2. I have installed jenkins & git on my local machine on Windows 10.
3. **Problem:**
   Facing error while setup git repo with jenkins.Please see the screen-shot.
   [image]

Error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe ls-remote -h -- ssh://username@server_ip:/srv/repo.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: ssh: Could not resolve hostname server_ip: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the exact value `ssh://user@serverIP:/srv/repo.git`? Or are you replacing th with the value of your own server IP address, and `repo` with the repo name, etc?

Comment: Can you, from a terminal on your local machine, execute the command given by Jenkins? Verbatim.

Comment: @evolutionxbox.. i am changing the user, server ip &repo with the correct values..

Comment: May you try @YSC's idea?

Comment: @YSC..what is mean by "execute the command given by Jenkins?"..? what command is given by jenkins.?

Comment: You've put a red square around it. If you had (as it's preferred on SO) copy/pasted it as text in your question I could give you a better pointer. But you havn't.

Comment: @YSC..i have added the error text in my question.

Comment: May you run the command `git ls-remote -h -- ssh://username@server_ip:/srv/repo.git HEAD` and tell us the output? (replacing all the relevant parts)

Comment: while using the command you suggest showing error: "Invalid remote URL: git ls-remote -h -- ssh://username@server_ip:/srv/repo.git"

Comment: @DineshChandra did you replace the bits like username, server_ip, repo, etc?

Comment: .@evolutionxbox ..definitely i am using correct user name,server ip and repo path. as i have mentioned in my question that i am able to clone the repo by using the same command on git bash ..but having issue with jenkins only..

Comment: thank you, it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the solution of this issue..there was an issue of authentication of jenkins with git server. Just resolve using below steps:

1. Open git bash on local machine and generate public/private keyes using command: ssh-keygen
2. Copy the id_rsa.pub content to C:\Users\your_windows_user_name here.ssh\known_hosts
3. In jenkins got to Source Code Management->Git->Credentials add
4. In Jenkins select Kind->SSH Username with private key, Enter directly -> Paste the private generated private key here from the file
5. on Linux Server go to .ssh/authorized_keys and paste the C:\Users\your_windows_user_name here.ssh\id_rsa.pub file content here
6. In jenkins project configuration go to the "Source code management" section and choose git->Repositary url-> paste this ssh://user@serverIP:/srv/repo.git
7. Select the Credentials which we create in step no. 3 & 4.

Answer (score -1):

You have to exchange 'server_ip' with the IP of your server.

Username should to set to the correct one, too.
You said that you can clone like this

```
ssh://user@serverIP:/srv/repo.git
```

But Jenkins is trying to clone like this

```
ssh://user@server_ip:/srv/repo.git
```

Comment: Quoting OP: "i am able to clone this using the command ssh://user@serverIP:/srv/repo.git."

Comment: Yeah, maybe because for whatever reason the OP can resolve 'serverIP'. But that not mean that Jenkins is able to do the same. Additionally OP is doing two different things. HE is able to clone with *user@serverIP' but Jenkins is trying clone with 'user@server_ip'    That's not the same ;)

Comment: @YSC Then the OP is contradicting himself - there are just two possibilities, `server_IP` can either resolve or not.

Comment: I agree the question is bad, it doesn't make this answer good nonetheless. You're making assumptions where you could ask OP for precisions, or flag the question low qual.